# Delphi 7 Add Constant List of Values to TStringList

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tstringlist

I'm attempting to add a constant list of values to a TStringList.

My first thought was to use the DelimitedText attribute, but it's broken in 7 (space is always a delimiter), plus, it overwrites whatever is already in the TStringList.

I looked at the AddStrings, but I'd like to avoid instantiating another object if I can help it.

I could just iterate over a constant array of string, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything easier (or else) than iteration (assuming we are talking about a constant array of strings). Recent versions has an overload for adding `TArray<string>`.

Comment: @TLama Alright, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: Why ? It's not that bad. Even the recent version of Delphi must iterate a passed `TArray<string>`. You just lock the string list with a `BeginUpdate`, `EndUpdate` block and iterate the array adding its elements. It's a very short piece of quite efficient code.

Comment: Its seems like there should be an easier way and there is an easier way are not the same thing.  Sometimes there is just a way.